# KERAS: Pretraining of a CNN model and after use it for a CNN-LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I have this cnn model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_rows,n_cols,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1,3)))
#...
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu')) #needed?
model.add(Dense(3)) #default linear activation
```

And train it

After I want to use the weights of this CNN, to use them in a CNN-LSTM model.

So I have something like this:

```
#Load from previous CNN (pre-trained!) (up to Flatten()) and use TimeDistributed on them
model.add(LSTM(1024, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
```

Does it make sense? How it is possible to do it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. However, in order to successfully implement this new model, you need to use the Functional API (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) in order to achieve this.

Below I am giving you an example on how you can add new layers to a pretrained model.

```
# Initialize the base model
# Say that this is the cnn model which is pretrained
base_model = cnn_model(input_shape=(n_rows, n_cols, 1))
base_model.trainable = False

# Adding the first lstm layer
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024,activation='relu',return_sequences='True')(base_model.output)

# Adding the second lstm layer
x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1024, activation='relu',return_sequences='False')(x)

# Adding the output
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='linear')(x)

# Final model creation
model = Model(inputs=[base_model.input], outputs=[output])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My doubt:
1. In CNN model after flatten(), what is better to put? (1, 2, 3 dense layers?)
2. How to say please stop CNN weights up to flatten()?
3. How to add TimeDistributed and use them?

Thanks!

Comment: You may put only one dense layer. Please ask a separate question for all your other questions, because the initial question has been answered; this is how stack overflow works. Also kindly accept and upvote the answer provided. Thank you.